# Accessing state of another component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components, one of them has a state, which I want to access from the other component.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {test:"Hello World"};
  }
  render() {
    return(<Bar {...this.state} />);
  }
}

class Bar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(<h1>{this.props.test}</h1>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.Render(
  <Bar />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I googled around a bit, but since I'm new to JS and React I think I misunderstood something, because this code doesn't work. From my understanding it should display "Hello World", but instead nothing happens.

Comment: Try rendering `Foo` as the root component instead

Comment: Nothing happens still

Comment: since you weren't rendering the parent node of <Foo /> bar wasn't receiving it's state as props

Comment: @Vincent D'amour's answer is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work. Render Foo instead of Bar

```
ReactDOM.Render(
  <Foo />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Also use `ReactDOM.render` insetad of `ReactDom.Render` (lower case for render)

Here a working version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOemzW?editors=1010

Comment: Idk if I'm missing something really obvious here? It doesn't work, even though everyone says it should :/

Comment: Can you paste all of your code. Based on your question we cannot find why it's not working

Comment: Currently I'm just learning the basics of React, so that IS my complete code. My HTML file looks like this: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/dXsxtxru)

Comment: There is no import statement, if this this all of your code, import react like this `import React from 'react';` and reactDOM like this `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Comment: That still didn't fix it. Also, I can get it to render even without imports, if I don't try to use states from a different component.

Comment: Can you also paste your HTML file?

Comment: I just figured it out. It was an extremely dumb mistake, as I suspected... It's supposed to be ReactDOM.render(), not ReactDOM.Render() -,- Thanks for being patient and putting up with me though

Comment: Ahah no problem, I edited my answer pointing it out with a working example just before seeing your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have three things going on. First as others have said, you should be using `<Foo />` in your render method, and secondly, render should be lower case, (`ReactDOM.render`) not `ReactDOM.Render`.

Finally, trying to load the script.js file with babel they way you are, generates the following error for me in my developer console:

babel.min.js:24 Failed to load file:///C:script.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

The following works. Just put it in one file and open.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.3/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.3/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    class Foo extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {test:"Hello World"};
      }
      render() {
        return(<Bar {...this.state} />);
      }
    }

    class Bar extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return(<h1>{this.props.test}</h1>);
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Foo />,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```